# Display French instead of English while using \SIlist

Tags: siunitx, languages, units

While using `\SIlist` from `siunitx` package, say something like `\SIlist{-3;3}{\Pa}`, the following is displayed:

> -3 Pa and 3 Pa

However, I am writing a report in French. How can I change the default language of the `siunitx` package in French to get the following?

> -3 Pa et 3 Pa

("et" means "and" in French)

I've already tried using `\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}` and `\sisetup{locale =FR,detect-all,}` in the preamble, but it doesn't work.

Comment: siunitx uses the translator package for the translation, and it must get the french option. So either give the option as document option as in the answer of Joseph or load translator before siunitx with your option: `\usepackage[frenchb]{translator}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work with no special set up

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\SIlist{-3;3}{\pascal}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you it works! Btw your documentation on CTAN about siunitx is very helpful to get started with this package.